# Are simplicial finite CW complexes and simplicial finite simplicial sets equivalent?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

**Edit** Originally the question was whether an arbitrary diagram of finite CW complexes can be approximated by a diagram of finite simplicial sets. In view of Tyler's comment, this was clearly asking for too much. I restricted the question from arbitrary diagrams to simplicial diagrams.

---

It is well-known that for any finite CW complex $K$ one can construct a finite simplicial set whose geometric realization is equivalent to $K$. But the construction is not functorial.

Suppose we have a simplicial object in finite CW complexes. Can one always construct a simplicial object of finite simplicial sets, whose levelwise geometric realization is connected to the original diagram by a zig-zag of levelwise weak equivalences?

One may ask a similar question in a more general context. Suppose we have an $\infty$-category $\mathcal C$. Suppose $A$ is a collection of (say compact) objects of $\mathcal C$. Let $CW^f(A)$ be the category of finite cellular objects generated by $A$. Roughly speaking, $CW^f(A)$ consists of objects that can be built as a finite homotopy colimit of objects of $A$. I am leaving the definition of $CW^f(A)$ a little vague - feel free to use any reasonable notion. Let $S_\bullet^f(A)$ be the category of simplicial objects in $\mathcal C$ that in each simplicial degree are a finite sum of elements of $A$, and are degenerate above some dimension. Geometric realization gives a functor $S_\bullet^f(A)\to CW^f(A)$. Now we have an obvious generalization of the question:

Suppose we have a simplicial object in $CW^f(A)$. Can we find a simplicial object in $S_\bullet^f(A)$ whose levelwise geometric realization is levelwise (weakly) equivalent to it? If it is not true in general, is there a reasonable sufficient assumption?

Comment: Hi Greg, I suspect that the map $B\Bbb N \to CW$, representing $S^1$ with the endomorphisms $2^k$ for $k > 0$, can't be realized by a diagram of finite simplicial sets, but to prove it I'd want to come up with some explicit growth condition on the number of edges needed to represent elements of $\pi_1$ for a fixed finite model. This may be a little harder for s.sets than for $\infty$-categories because the mapping complexes aren't Kan complexes.

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks. This sounds right and suggests I should impose a local finiteness condition on the indexing diagram (such as, there can be only finitely many morphisms between any two objects). What I really wanted to know was about simplicial objects: can any simplicial object in finite CW complexes be approximated by a simplicial object in finite simplicial sets? I will edit the question.

Comment: In Tyler's example, can't we just observe that for any finite simplicial set $K$, only finitely many maps on $\pi_1$ are induced by endomorphisms $K\to K$? This is because there are only finitely many maps $K\to K$ in total.

Comment: @AchimKrause That is, indeed, a great deal simpler than what I had in mind.

Comment: A possible more general finiteness condition could be the assumption that every object in the diagram has finitely many maps out of it. (This has [popped up](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2706889) in some inductive constructions I ran into; examples include finite diagrams and semisimplicial objects.)

Comment: If the "more general" version is purely homotopical, Tyler's example isn't a counterexample, is it? (a counterexample to an even more general version) And a nitpick, just a problem for objects, if a "finite homotopy colimit" includes retracts, then you run into Wall finiteness problems, but @R.vanDobbendeBruyn's version doesn't.

Comment: @BenWieland yes, absolutely. you can replace each object in a diagram with any weakly equivalent object and get an equivalent diagram at the cost of working coherently.

Comment: @BenWieland I am feeling a little slow. Why it is not a counterexample?

Comment: The point of the original question is that a model does not support every morphism. Tyler's example of a functor from $B\mathbb N$ is just the choice of an object and a morphism. If you allow Kan complexes or finite CW complexes, then they are cofibrant-fibrant and thus they support arbitrary morphisms. In the purely homotopical setting, the object supports the morphism. Tyler's example was $S^1$, which is as nicely cellular as you can imagine: represent it as the constant simplicial object. Maybe having to spell out the cells allows counterexamples, but not that one.